# Scanf() does not recognize space before %c

Tags: c, variables, if-statement, whitespace, scanf

Observe this chunk of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char choice;

    printf("\n\nDo you want to play again (Y/N)? ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    if (choice != 'Y' || choice != 'y' || choice != 'N' || choice != 'n')
    {
        printf("\n\nYou didn\'t enter a decision.");
    }

return 0;
}
```

I want the printf() to prompt the user to input either Y or N. The scanf() will fill the user's input in the variable *choice*. If *choice* is not equal to Y, y, N, or n, it will tell the user that he/she didn't enter a decision. Then, the program will end.

However, when I inputted Y or N, it printed "You didn't enter a decision." This should only happen if I don't enter Y or N (lowercase or uppercase).

I even put a space before the conversion character so the scanf() wouldn't read the newline character (\n).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try printing `choice` to see what character was being extracted?

Comment: You need to check your condition in the `if` statement again.

Comment: I printed choice. It printed 'Y' when I inputted Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
if (choice != 'Y' || choice != 'y' || choice != 'N' || choice != 'n')
```

to

```
if (choice != 'Y' && choice != 'y' && choice != 'N' && choice != 'n')
```

otherwise whether you enter any of `Y, y, N, n` *or any other character* (as pointed by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389172/scanf-does-not-recognize-space-before-c/25389202#comment39597082_25389202)), the expression in `if` will be evaluated to `true`.

Comment: Or indeed if you enter any other character — no single character is simultaneously equal to 'y' and 'Y' and 'n' and 'N'.

Comment: `choice = tolower(choice); if (choice != 'y' && choice != 'n')`

Comment: (At one time, John Vearr asked 'why'): Take two examples.  Suppose `choice == 'Y'`; then the first term `choice != 'Y'` evaluates to false, so the second term is evaluated, and since `'Y' != 'y'`, it evaluates to true, so the `if` condition overall evaluates to true.  Suppose `choice == 'y'`; then the first term `choice != 'Y'` evaluates to true, so the `if` condition overall evaluates to true.  In general, `if (a == b || a == c || …)` makes sense, and `if (a != b && a != c && …)` makes sense, but neither `if (a != b || a != c || …)` nor `if (a == b && a == c && …)` makes sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Much explanatory than the given answer :)

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for explaining the code to me.

I would like to thank everyone who helped me fix my error :).

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Just Include Else Like Following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char choice;

    printf("\n\nDo you want to play again (Y/N)? ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    if (choice != 'Y' || choice != 'y' || choice != 'N' || choice != 'n')
    {
        printf("\n\nYou didn\'t enter a decision.");
    }


return 0;
}
```